# Python3 how to get current and next directory from os.walk?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do I traverse through a directory and print out the current directory and the next directory in the iteration?

```
currentdir = '/tmp/test'
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(currentdir):
    print("Current dir: {}: ".format(root))
    print("Next dir: {}: ".format(next(os.walk(root))))
```

Comment: I don't understand your problem. You get all the dirs inside root that are being visited next in `dirs`. What other information do you need?

Comment: what do you mean by next directory.?

Comment: Next directory in the for loop. The dirs returns a list of subdirectories but I need the single next directory that would be root on the next iteration in the for loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like so

```
currentdir = '/tmp/test'
itr = iter(os.walk(currentdir))
root, dirs, files = next(itr)  # get first element

for next_root, next_dirs, next_files in itr:  # get second element onwards
    print("Current dir: {}: ".format(root))
    print("Next dir: {}: ".format(next_root))
    root, dirs, files = next_root, next_dirs, next_files
```

Comment: n.b.The `iter(...)` is redundant since `os.walk` return an iterator. However, I'm going to leave it here since for some iterables it is necessary and it is negligible performance loss to call `iter(...)` (since `iterator.__iter__` is just `return self`)

Answer (score 1):

os.walk returns an iterator, that can be run only once.

If memory is not an issue, you can put the results into a list, and then iterate over the list:

```
roots = [root for root, _, _ in os.walk(current_dir)]

for root, next_root in zip(roots, roots[1:]):
    print(root, "next = ", next_root)

# and if you need the last one
print(roots[-1], "last one - no next")
```

If memory is an issue, you can use itertools.tee and itertools.islice to manipulate the iterators, but in this case, FHTMitchell's answer would be easier to read in my opinion.